# POST form data via rest

Tags: javascript, html

I have this endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/createUser")
public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {...}
```

I have an HTML page where I want to create a user.

```
    <form>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br>

        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

What is a good and simple way to post this request?

Comment: Study some tutorials on how html forms work and how to process them in your back end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using **async / await**

Add this to your button `<button onclick="send()">Submit</button>`
when it's clicked then call a function like `send()` here an example

`async function send() {}`

and inside the function you can use the below code snippet to send the data to your endpoint

```
async function send() {
    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    
  
        const data = {username, password};
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        await fetch('/createUser', options); 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you assume he needs to do an async call? Maybe just using an html form itself is enough.

Comment: Not to mention that OP would need to expect JSON and this solution doesn't prevent the default form submit process

Comment: What does OP mean?

Comment: OP = Original Post or Original Poster

Comment: Yes, i need it to be JSON

Comment: Well than you can use this solution, I would do it this way

Comment: @charlietfl okay thanks now it's clear ^^

Answer (score -1):

I still don't understand what you want to do, but if you want to post that form, then you can add a Attribute to the `<form>` tag. Just do `<form method="POST">` and then use Back-end to listen the POST.

Comment: Which endpoint is it doing that POST request on?

Comment: It will POST to the current url. So that mean you have to make your app listen to the current url. If you post to `localhost:3000/login`, so you have to make your back-end listen POSTs in url `localhost:3000/login`.

Comment: Dude, im using it for my login functions.